# Jenkins: Daily email report about multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins

Can Jenkins send a daily/weekly... email report about multiple jobs statuses? Basically a daily email containing:

[image: jenkins view]

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit plugin for that, but you can create a job and pull stats from other plugins like

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/build-metrics-plugin